# Jupytext pre-commit config when notebooks are ignored in git

Tags: git, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

My current hook looks like this:

```
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    -   id: jupytext
        name: jupytext
        entry: jupytext
        language: conda
        files: '^notebooks/(.*\.py|.*\.ipynb)$'
        args: [--sync, --pipe, black]
```

The directory structure is like this:

```
.
├── notebooks
│   └── dataset-exploration
│       └── 01-amplitude-exploration
│           └── amplitude_exploration.ipynb
├── [other folders]*
```

I have `*.ipynb` in my `.gitignore` file, which means that notebooks are ignored (because of git size issues), but I want pre-commit to automatically create/sync python scripts and their paired notebooks in each commit. But apparently because my hook is not working as intended, and no `*.py` file is being generated (or synced) from my `*.ipynb` files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pre-commit` only operates on checked in files -- since yours are gitignored you'll need to find some other way to synchronize them

one idea is to `always_run: true` and `pass_filenames: false` and list the notebooks to sync explicitly:

```yaml
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    -   id: jupytext
        name: jupytext
        entry: jupytext --sync --pipe black notebooks/foo.ipynb notebooks/bar.ipynb
        language: conda
        always_run: true
        pass_filenames: false
```

though this kind of defeats the purpose of the framework (you'd always run the slow operation all the time)

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit